# Nginx configuration for allow ip is not working deny all is working fine

Tags: linux, nginx

i create a new conf file to block all public ip to access and give only one public ip address(office public IP) to access. but when i try to access its shows the  "403 Forbidden nginx"

> ```
>     upstream backend_solr {
>          ip_hash;
>          server ip_address:port; 
> } 
> server {
>          listen 80;
>          server_name www.example.com;
>
>          index /example/admin.html;
>
>          charset utf-8;
>          access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log main;
>
>          location / {
>
>             allow **office_public_ip**;
>             deny all;
>             proxy_pass  http://backend_solr-01/;
>             proxy_set_header Host $host;
>             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>          }
>
>         location ~ /favicon\.ico {
>             root html;
>         }
>
>         location ~ /\. {
>             deny all;
>         }}
> ```

but in the logs it shows accessing to the public ip but forbidden

```
IP_Address - - [31/Jul/2017:12:43:05 +0800] "Get /example/admin.html HTTP/1.0" www.example.com "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" "my_office _IP" "-" "-" "-" 403 564 0.000 - - -
```

Comment: I think it should work if you remove "location ~ /\. {deny all;}" from the end of the file.

Comment: I cannot find a definition for `main` log format - But what is the IP address at the beginning of the log entry?

Comment: @Cninroh that location only matches URIs with a path element that *begins* with a `.`.

Comment: I remove the   "location ~ /\. {deny all;}" but no luck., the ip addess whch  i calling begining is the ip of the server whch connect to nginx and pass the example (tomcat server ip.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deny all` was not working for me because the traffic was being forwarded internally through a proxy.

Here is what ended up working for me:

```
upstream backend_solr {
    ip_hash;
    server ip_address:port; 
} 
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    index /example/admin.html;

     charset utf-8;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log main;

     location / {
         # **
         set $allow false;
         if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ " 12\.22\.22\.22?$")-public ip {
             set $allow true;
         }
         set $allow false;
         if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ " ?11\.123\.123\.123?$")- proxy ip {
             set $allow true;
         }
         if ($allow = false) {
             return 403 ;
         }
         # **
         proxy_pass  http://backend_solr-01/;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ /favicon\.ico {
        root html;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This nginx configuration works for me :

```
location / {   ## Use the request url, not the directory on the filesystem.
  allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;  ## Your specific IP
  deny all;
}
```

But you can place allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx outside the location if you want to deny or allow only a specific location.

Comment: Hi Noob, most of the articles suggest to do this method but its not working for me. when i deny all its deny my public ip also..that mean the allow my public ip is not working right.?

Comment: I think this part is denying all. location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }